# Shared projects referencing to solution level Nuget packages

Tags: .net, visual-studio

In visual studio 2015, having projects shared among different solutions with different physical path structure and using Nuget, is there a possibility to have a solution level Nuget packages folder and still make the project references work when switching from one solution to another?

**Example**

- Folder A

  - Solution A
  - Solutions

    - Solution B
  - Projects

    - Project A
    - Project B

**My research**

Searching on the web I have found [this](https://blog.stangroome.com/2013/11/26/nuget-reference-paths-for-projects-in-multiple-solutions/) article which introduces (yet another) NuGet package to solve the issue.

I was just wondering whether I have missed something and there is a simple solution without restructuring the solutions or extra Nuget packages.

Comment: Did you try to use symlinks?

Comment: Symlinks to the packages folder? How to tell Nuget where to download if you are using a build server thought? By default Nuget will restore to the current solution and the symlink folders may be empty.